# Why does my XPath selector return incorrect html tags by parsel

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, parsel

I am using Python to scrape html data and having trouble with the output result of my XPath selections. It always matches to the end of `</body></html>`

For example:

```
from parsel import Selector

html = '''
<div id='images'>
 <a href='image1.html'>Name: My image 10 <br /><img src='image1_thumb.jpg' /></a>
 <a href='image2.html'>Name: My image 2 <br /><img src='image2_thumb.jpg' /></a>
 <a href='image3.html'>Name: My image 30 <br /><img src='image3_thumb.jpg' /></a>
 <a href='image4.html'>Name: My image 40 <br /><img src='image4_thumb.jpg' /></a>
 <a href='image5.html'>Name: My image 5 <br /><img src='image5_thumb.jpg' /></a>
</div>
'''

selector = Selector(text=html)
elements = selector.xpath('//div[@id="images"]/a[4]')
print(elements.get())
```

The expected output would be:

```
<a href='image4.html'>Name: My image 40 <br /><img src='image4_thumb.jpg' /></a>
```

However, what I get is:

```
<a href="image4.html">Name: My image 40 <br><img src="image4_thumb.jpg"></a>
 <a href="image5.html">Name: My image 5 <br><img src="image5_thumb.jpg"></a>
</div></body></html>
```

Can someone explain why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Looks like a bug on `parsel` but since seems to be using `lxml` parts, look at [tail property](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html) and see if that helps

Comment: Python 3.10, parcel 1.7.0, the output is as expected

Comment: Maybe it's a bug. My previous running environment was Python 3.9.12 + parsel 1.7. When I upgraded Python to 3.9.16, the output results met my expectation